# Codeigniter: How to print array of arrays from view to model

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have an ajax where it passes the array of arrays or multidimensional/2 dimensional array and when I passed it to controller to model, I need to do a **Foreach** inside a function so that I can get the `$this->input->post('distance');` but I don't know how can I print the array of arrays in the model or get the array of arrays so that I can do a **Foreach**.

here is my ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: url + 'getBookTours',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           swal("Booked!", "", "success");
        },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           swal("Save Error!", "", "error");
        }
 });
```

and in my controller:

```
public function getBookTours(){
    $record = $this->mdl->bookTours();
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($record));
}
```

and in my model:

```
public function bookTours(){
      $info = array (
        'total_price' => $this->input->post('fare'),
        'total_distance_km' => $this->input->post('distance'),
        'status' => 1,
        'ip' => $this->getUserIP(),
        'booked' => $time,
      );
    return $info;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean array of objects ?

```
[{'total_price':636 .....},{'total_price':8484....}]
```

Fisrt convert you array to JSON
`var json = JSON.stringify(your_array);`
Change the ajax to following

```
data: {data : json},
```

In the php

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->post("data"),true);
foreach($data as $obj){
   //now you can access
   echo $obj["total_price"];
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but yes, you're corrent. its array of objects.